# Strongloop post operation with path parameter to rest api

Tags: rest, post, parameters, path, strongloop

I would like to know the POST operation with path parameters to any rest api from strong loop application.

Any sample example will help, I went through the strong loop documentation but it says only for get operation with query parameter not with path parameter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about built-in models REST API, otherwise your question makes little sense.

This is [very well documented](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API). For instance, for [`PersistedModel`](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API) each default method is described along with an example.